# Extract certificate chain information from signed X509 certificate (CSR response) in Android / BouncyCastle

Tags: android, x509certificate, bouncycastle, pkcs#12, android-keystore

**Am I able to extract certificate chain information from a CA-signed X509 client certificate using Android or BouncyCastle libs?**

I have an Android client that receives a CA-signed X509 certificate from a trusted server. I want to save the signed client certificate and my private key to a PKCS12 (.p12) file. I am currently doing this by creating a `KeyStore` object and adding the certificate and private key. When I add the client `PrivateKey` with the `KeyStore.setKeyEntry()` method, a `Certificate[] chain` is the last argument, which currently only contains the client certificate. **Will this prevent my certificate from being verifiable because I don't have the CA certificate in the `Certificate[] chain`?** And if yes, is it possible to populate a certificate chain with information extracted from the signed `X509Certificate`?

Most examples seem to load the CA chain from a PEM file, BKS trust store, or already have access to a list of certificates.

Here is what I have:

```
    X509Certificate cert;      // signed client cert
    PrivateKey pkey;           // client private key
    String password; 

    KeyStore store;
    store = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
    store.load(null, null);

    // adding the signed cert
    store.setCertificateEntry("Client certificate", cert);

    // creating the cert chain
    X509Certificate[] chain = new X509Certificate[1];
    chain[0] = cert;
    // add rest of the certs in the chain here

    // adding the private key   
    store.setKeyEntry("Client private key", pkey, password.toCharArray(), chain);

    FileOutputStream fos;
    fos = openFileOutput("clientCredentials.p12", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    store.store(fos, password.toCharArray());
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CA certificate(s) are not included in your signed certificate. You have to get them from somewhere (pre-install, download from trusted server, etc.). As for not installing the full chain, if the verifier already has access to necessary CA certificates, they can always verify your end entity certificate. How do you intend to use your key and certificate?

BTW, your call to `setCertificateEntry()` creates a trusted certificate entry which is probably not what you want with an end entity certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Please tell me if I am understanding this correctly. When verifying a certificate, the verifier also has to trust the chain that the certificate is using (via pre-install, download, etc.)? I suppose if you don't already trust the issuer you can't verify the certificate.

Comment: I am using the client credentials to establish a trusted SSL conection with my server. (And I already have the app creating a CSR, getting the client cert signed by my server, and the signed cert above is the server response. I am trying to store the pkey and signed cert on the client android device.) For `setCertificateEntry()` should I be using `setKeyEntry()` and pass the X509Certificate `getEncoded()` bytes instead? I am essentially trying to implement [OpenSSL's PKCS12_create function](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS12_create.html). Thanks again @nikolay-elenkov !

Comment: Right, the verifier needs to trust the issuer CA already, that's their trust anchor. `setKeyEntry()` should do the job for you: you will get a PKCS#12 file with the key and certificate and no CA certificates bundled.

Comment: Okay - the above `store.setKeyEntry()` with client private key and a chain containing only the client certificate is good for my PKCS12 file? I also removed the `store.setCertificateEntry()` call. (And I don't need to import the CA truststore, extract the issuer certificate that matches the client certificate issuer, and add it to the chain with `chain[1] = caCert;` ?) Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Unless the app that will use the PKCS#12 file expects to find an issuer cert inside, yes.